# decorator inner function is not being called

Tags: python

I have a decorator called decorator_require_api, This decorator is supposed to check if an API is valid.  The route works and I do get the response, but the decorator is not working.  The decorator outer functions work, but the inner function is not.  Not sure what I am missing. I am not getting any errors or anything, it just simply skips over the inner function of the decorator.

```
from flask import Blueprint
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, jsonify
from .models import Security

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)


def decorator_require_api(original_function):
    @wraps(original_function)
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):

        print("in decorator")
        # Gets API Header
        security = request.headers.get('api_key')
        # flask.logger.info('API Key is ' + str(security))

        # If no key is present it will stop right here.
        if not security:
            return jsonify({"msg": "API KEY REQUIRED"}), 401

        check_api = Security.query.filter_by(api_key=security).first()
        if not check_api:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Invalid Key"}), 401
        return original_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_function


@decorator_require_api
@views.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return 'Testing'
```

Comment: You should put your custom decorator *after* the router, or the router never sees your decorated new function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your custom decorator **after** the the router, otherwise your router does not "see" the decorated function, but rather just `hello_world`. In otherwords, for the flask router to call your decorator, it needs to be encapsulate the entire thing.

##### Code

```py
@views.route('/', methods=['GET']) # Before the custom decorator
@decorator_require_api # After the router decorator.
def hello_world():
    return 'Testing'
```